# UIView, UITableView frame misalignment iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uicollectionview, xcode6

I am using `UITableViewController`,`UICollectionViewController` in my app. On `ViewDidLoad` the view looks great like the following.[image]

But after if I undergo its respective detail view and back to `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` it align like the following[image]

I even tried setting `self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height);` on `viewDidAppear` but no luck.

Here is my tableView properties: (I also tried both check/uncheck these properties). Anyone here kindly suggest the possible solution or reason for this problem..

NOTE: Autolayout for storyboard is **NOT** used..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your UITableViewController ViewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: The problem now a raised on load itself Like this(http://i.stack.imgur.com/XYNWM.png) on load

Comment: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; //use this in ur cellforindexpath